# Router outlet won't show until router is clicked

Tags: angular

I am trying to use routes to in a single page application, so far I've setup everything. But the problem is, the children doesn't display in the router outlet initially, I have to click the nav before it shows.

Here's what I got so far

Routing.ts

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
{
path: '',
component: OGComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'check',
    component: CheckComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'check/:id',
    component: CheckInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'Company',
    component: CompanyComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'versions',
    component: VersionsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'Contact',
        component: ContactComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'About',
        component: AboutComponent
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

}
];

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let section of homeSec">
    <mat-list-item class="title">{{section.name}}</mat-list-item>
    <div *ngFor="let subSection of section?.subSections">
        <mat-list-item>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="{{subSection.name}}" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">{{subSection.name}}</a>
        </mat-list-item>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: You need to set the default empty path with redirect to the entry you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adding empty path with redirect to home.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'Company', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Something like below:

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
{
path: '',
component: OGComponent,
children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Company', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'check',
    component: CheckComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'check/:id',
    component: CheckInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'Company',
    component: CompanyComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'versions',
    component: VersionsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'Home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'Contact',
        component: ContactComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'About',
        component: AboutComponent
      },
    ]
  },
],
}
];
```

Comment: I've edited my question. Sorry for the confusion. But the 'home' component is under a 'company' component

Comment: Can you provide an executable example? Like stackblitz?

Comment: Can you at least  put all the route in this file?

Comment: I've put all my routes in the file

Comment: Adding empty path on your chidlren routes, update the answer.

Comment: The problem here is in the HomeComponent. Now it does load the 1st child the ContactComponent on init of Home but the AboutComponent doesn't load. I got it by adding { path: '', redirectTo: 'Contact', pathMatch: 'full' }, in the children of HomeComponent

Comment: Sorry, cannot help if you cannot reproduce it on stackblitz.